# indexPath and indexPath.section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

UITableView is needed in a lot of iPhone Apps, I also read about it a lot, I know indexPath.row is the current row but I don't know what indexPath and indexPath.section is. Could you explain me thoroughly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple, section is w.r.t table and row is w.r.t section..

From the below pic you can know it in better way, for more info you can have a look at apple docs from the other answers..

[image]

Comment: This give me a visualised explanation of what I asked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Well just as the `indexPath.row` is the current row, the `indexPath.Section` represents the current section of the `UITableView`

Please read this simple illustrated documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views

Answer (score 1):

Some time for Indexing and for Header title of some data , and different data with different section in one table then here required sections in the table.. here indexPath have this two value stored with row and section which define the index of record with section and row.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here can explain you thoroughly. But you will get it if you will learn it by your self only. We can provide you reference only.

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview)

Learn & observe this, play with some examples given in it. You will experience a lot by yourself.